# Java Script not working on Subpages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey this is my JS and jQuery code, I've only worked on the index.html. My problem happens when I move in a subpage, in fact my script stops working. Everything is included in the subpages and this is my simple menu. It is correcly working on the index page.

Update, i figured easy pie chart is causing the error when its not used on the subpage, but i dont know how to prevent the error, it only occurs when the counter is not on the subpage, how can i skip js looking for the container if its not on the page ?

this row is causing the error :

counterScrollFromTop = $countersContainer.parent().parent().position().top;

```
! function(a, b) {
    "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = b(require("jquery")) : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], b) : b(a.jQuery)
}(this, function(a) {
    var b = function(a, b) {
            var c, d = document.createElement("canvas");
            a.appendChild(d), "undefined" != typeof G_vmlCanvasManager && G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(d);
            var e = d.getContext("2d");
            d.width = d.height = b.size;
            var f = 1;
            window.devicePixelRatio > 1 && (f = window.devicePixelRatio, d.style.width = d.style.height = [b.size, "px"].join(""), d.width = d.height = b.size * f, e.scale(f, f)), e.translate(b.size / 2, b.size / 2), e.rotate((-0.5 + b.rotate / 180) * Math.PI);
            var g = (b.size - b.lineWidth) / 2;
            b.scaleColor && b.scaleLength && (g -= b.scaleLength + 2), Date.now = Date.now || function() {
                return +new Date
            };
            var h = function(a, b, c) {
                    c = Math.min(Math.max(-1, c || 0), 1);
                    var d = 0 >= c ? !0 : !1;
                    e.beginPath(), e.arc(0, 0, g, 0, 2 * Math.PI * c, d), e.strokeStyle = a, e.lineWidth = b, e.stroke()
                },
                i = function() {
                    var a, c;
                    e.lineWidth = 1, e.fillStyle = b.scaleColor, e.save();
                    for (var d = 24; d > 0; --d) d % 6 === 0 ? (c = b.scaleLength, a = 0) : (c = .6 * b.scaleLength, a = b.scaleLength - c), e.fillRect(-b.size / 2 + a, 0, c, 1), e.rotate(Math.PI / 12);
                    e.restore()
                },
                j = function() {
                    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function(a) {
                        window.setTimeout(a, 1e3 / 60)
                    }
                }(),
                k = function() {
                    b.scaleColor && i(), b.trackColor && h(b.trackColor, b.trackWidth || b.lineWidth, 1)
                };
            this.getCanvas = function() {
                return d
            }, this.getCtx = function() {
                return e
            }, this.clear = function() {
                e.clearRect(b.size / -2, b.size / -2, b.size, b.size)
            }, this.draw = function(a) {
                b.scaleColor || b.trackColor ? e.getImageData && e.putImageData ? c ? e.putImageData(c, 0, 0) : (k(), c = e.getImageData(0, 0, b.size * f, b.size * f)) : (this.clear(), k()) : this.clear(), e.lineCap = b.lineCap;
                var d;
                d = "function" == typeof b.barColor ? b.barColor(a) : b.barColor, h(d, b.lineWidth, a / 100)
            }.bind(this), this.animate = function(a, c) {
                var d = Date.now();
                b.onStart(a, c);
                var e = function() {
                    var f = Math.min(Date.now() - d, b.animate.duration),
                        g = b.easing(this, f, a, c - a, b.animate.duration);
                    this.draw(g), b.onStep(a, c, g), f >= b.animate.duration ? b.onStop(a, c) : j(e)
                }.bind(this);
                j(e)
            }.bind(this)
        },
        c = function(a, c) {
            var d = {
                barColor: "#ef1e25",
                trackColor: "#f6f6f6",
                scaleColor: "#dfe0e0",
                scaleLength: 5,
                lineCap: "round",
                lineWidth: 3,
                trackWidth: void 0,
                size: 110,
                rotate: 0,
                animate: {
                    duration: 1e3,
                    enabled: !0
                },
                easing: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
                    return b /= e / 2, 1 > b ? d / 2 * b * b + c : -d / 2 * (--b * (b - 2) - 1) + c
                },
                onStart: function() {},
                onStep: function() {},
                onStop: function() {}
            };
            if ("undefined" != typeof b) d.renderer = b;
            else {
                if ("undefined" == typeof SVGRenderer) throw new Error("Please load either the SVG- or the CanvasRenderer");
                d.renderer = SVGRenderer
            }
            var e = {},
                f = 0,
                g = function() {
                    this.el = a, this.options = e;
                    for (var b in d) d.hasOwnProperty(b) && (e[b] = c && "undefined" != typeof c[b] ? c[b] : d[b], "function" == typeof e[b] && (e[b] = e[b].bind(this)));
                    e.easing = "string" == typeof e.easing && "undefined" != typeof jQuery && jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.easing[e.easing]) ? jQuery.easing[e.easing] : d.easing, "number" == typeof e.animate && (e.animate = {
                        duration: e.animate,
                        enabled: !0
                    }), "boolean" != typeof e.animate || e.animate || (e.animate = {
                        duration: 1e3,
                        enabled: e.animate
                    }), this.renderer = new e.renderer(a, e), this.renderer.draw(f), a.dataset && a.dataset.percent ? this.update(parseFloat(a.dataset.percent)) : a.getAttribute && a.getAttribute("data-percent") && this.update(parseFloat(a.getAttribute("data-percent")))
                }.bind(this);
            this.update = function(a) {
                return a = parseFloat(a), e.animate.enabled ? this.renderer.animate(f, a) : this.renderer.draw(a), f = a, this
            }.bind(this), this.disableAnimation = function() {
                return e.animate.enabled = !1, this
            }, this.enableAnimation = function() {
                return e.animate.enabled = !0, this
            }, g()
        };
    a.fn.easyPieChart = function(b) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var d;
            a.data(this, "easyPieChart") || (d = a.extend({}, b, a(this).data()), a.data(this, "easyPieChart", new c(this, d)))
        })
    }
});

var $window = $(window);

var $pb = $('.c-counter__progress-bar').parent(),
    $sb = $('.c-counter__single-bar'),
    $countersContainer = $('<div class="c-counter__container">');
if ($pb.length) {
    $sb.each(function() {
        var $text = $(this).children('.c-counter__text').text(),
            $head = $(this).children('.c-counter__headline').text(),
            val = $(this).children('.c-counter__bar').data('value'),
            color = $(this).children('.c-counter__bar').css('background-color');

        var $counter = $('<div>', {
                class: 'c-counter__item'
            })
            .append(
                $('<div>', {
                    class: 'chart',
                    'data-count': val,
                    'data-percent': 100,
                    'data-bar-color': color
                })
                .html($('<span>')),
                $('<h4>', {
                    class: 'c-counter__headline'
                }).text($head, $text),
                $('<p>', {
                    class: 'c-counter__text'
                }).text($text)
            );

        $counter.appendTo($countersContainer);
    });
    $pb.css('text-align', 'center').append($countersContainer);


}

function counter(targetNumber, duration) {

    var currentNum = 0,
        beatDuration = duration / targetNumber,
        $this = $(this);

    var interval = setInterval(function() {

        $this.text(++currentNum);

        if (currentNum >= targetNumber)
            clearInterval(interval);

    }, beatDuration)
}

function easyPieChart(i) {

    if ($('.chart').length < i - 1)
        return;

    var $currentChart = $('.chart').eq(i),
        $currentCounter = $currentChart.children('span'),
        targetNumber = $currentChart.data('count'),
        animationDuration = 1000;

    counter.call($currentCounter, targetNumber, animationDuration);

    $currentChart.easyPieChart({
        animate: animationDuration,
        size: 140,
        lineWidth: 7,
        scaleColor: false,
        lineCap: "",
        onStop: function() {
            easyPieChart(++i);
        }
    })
}

function initPieChart() {

    var windowScrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
        window_2_3_height = windowHeight * (2 / 3),
        scrollTopAnd_2_3 = windowScrollTop + window_2_3_height,
        counterScrollFromTop = $countersContainer.parent().parent().position().top;

    console.log(
        'windowScrollTop is: ' + windowScrollTop + ', ',
        'windowHeight is: ' + windowHeight + ', ',
        'window_2_3_height is: ' + window_2_3_height + ', ',
        'scrollTopAnd_2_3 is: ' + scrollTopAnd_2_3 + ', ',
        'counterScrollFromTop is: ' + counterScrollFromTop + ', '
    );

    if (counterScrollFromTop < scrollTopAnd_2_3) {

        easyPieChart(0);

        console.log('easyPieChart initialized');

        $window.off('scroll', initPieChart);
    }
}

$window.on('scroll', initPieChart).scroll();
```

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that jQuery is referenced with the appropriate path?

Comment: whats printed in your console??

Comment: paste the errors raised after loading a subpage, also if your website is live share your subpage url with us

Comment: i just figured it out , one plugin i use is causing an error main.js:195 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined ,  on the index the plugin is used (easypiechart) , on the sub pages not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out i just have to check with switch case if the class exist

var counter = $('.c-counter');
switch (counter.length) {
    case 1:
..code to execute 
}